# Show empty spaces in DRF(generics.ListCreateAPIView)

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get all the records from the table through the API. The desired amount is output, but it is empty. How do I fix this?

Model.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views.py

```
class AuthorList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   queryset = Author.objects.all()
   model = Author
   serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
```

Serializers.py

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name',)
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, I have two objects, but an empty json is output.

P.S: In console I can see my QuerySet with data: `<QuerySet [test, Pavel]>`

Answer (score 1):

Either @Fyzzy good's answer or better still, use a `ModelSerializer` instead of a `Serializer` as it automatically captures the model's fields instead of explicit definition in the serializer. And from what you have in the serializer's Meta class, it seems using `ModelSerializer` was what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `fields = ('name',)` to `name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)`